# When do I need to define a JmsListenerContainerFactory bean?

Tags: spring-jms

I am starting with JMS and I've got a couple of examples. Both work as expected, but one of them in its config class has a `@Bean` definition of a `JmsListenerContainerFactory`. The other one is not having any `JmsListenerContainerFactory` bean.

In the first example if I comment the bean definition the listener stops receiving messages. AFAIK `JmsListenerContainerFactory` is `@JMSListener` support and is created by default. In my understanding I can define mine if I need some customization, but in my example there is nothing special on that bean definition, just the concurrency setting.
Here you have bean definition:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("1-1"); //nro. min-max consumers
    return factory;
}
```

So, please enlighten me about the need of that bean.

Comment: I believe that there were only 7 ways to instantiate a message listener and folks saw the need for more....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, it automatically configures a container factory using the properties in application.yml/properties.

If you are NOT using Spring Boot, you have to define your own factory.